# Multiple build's results to be reported on separate lines to Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I am new to Jenkins and Gerrit. I am using version of Gerrit (2.8.5) & Jenkins (1.596.2).

I have written multiple jobs in jenkins with Gerrit event trigger "patchset created". I wanted the results to be displayed on separate lines in Gerrit under reviewer tab.

E.g.

Job1: Commit message check

Job2: Build compile

In Gerrit, under reviewer I want verdict from both jobs to be displayed separately. i.e. 
    Reviewer        Code-Review                      Verified

```
Job1            X                   

Job2                                             X
```

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit trigger plugin is not providing that. But you can use gerrit API to put +1 / -1 for anything you want. One API call - one comment :)

Comment: Any updates on this? Maybe a link to an issue tracking this subject. Commenting workaround gives a very poor UX.

Comment: The only way to do it is by using two different bots for each trigger.